# Flutter: Maintain state when navigating to different page

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following code which creates a Listview and adds an icon to the end of each item. This icon can be tapped in order to highlight it.

The problem is, when I navigate away from the page the items are deselected. I am using `Navigator.of` to load the Listview:

```
Navigator.of(context)
          .push(MaterialPageRoute<Null>(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return new LikedList();
            }));
```

Full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './images.dart';

class LikedList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LikedListState createState() => _LikedListState();
}

class _LikedListState extends State<LikedList> {
  List<bool> _likes = List.filled(ImagesState.likes.length,true);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Liked List'),
      ),
      body: ListView.separated(
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(),
        itemCount: ImagesState.likes.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final item = ImagesState.likes[index];
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(item),
            trailing: IconButton(
              icon: _likes[index]
                  ? Icon(
                      Icons.favorite_border,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    )
                  : Icon(
                      Icons.favorite,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  print(_likes);
                  _likes[index] = !_likes[index];
                  print(_likes);
                });
              },
            ),
            onLongPress: () {
              setState(() {
                print(ImagesState.likes[index]);
                ImagesState.likes.removeAt(index);
              });
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you want item to be selected when you get back to the screen?

Comment: I want the selected item in the Listiview to still be selected when you navigate away from and then back to, the Listview

Comment: Where is the code of moving from LikedList

Comment: Currently when I navigate to LikedList there is a back arrow automatically added to the top left which takes me back to where I was.

Comment: That is the right behaviour you are having right now, that should be deselected, but even if you want you can create static field in the app

Comment: You you mean add the `static` keyword to `List<bool> _likes = List.filled(ImagesState.likes.length,true);`?

If that is the expected behaviour, what do I need to change to make it act the way I need it to?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214519/discussion-between-jitsm555-and-cjw).

Comment: one approach could be to lift the state(keep the model to hold) one level up in tree and can use 'Provider' to refresh the state.